# R: how to direct neuralnet progressing output to specific file?

Tags: r, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

While the **neuralnet** is progressing in **R**, it generate the `steps/ min thresh` in the console as follow

```
hidden: 1    thresh: 1    rep: 1/1    steps:     1000   min thresh: 5506.086127
                                                 2000   min thresh: 131.2950623
                                                 2831   error: 1595263.315  time: 3.11 secs
```

My question … is how to direct such output to specific file?

Comment: I know this might be difficult quarry … this is why I appreciate your help …

Comment: Could you include the code you use to get the output you want?

Comment: `net.sqrt <- neuralnet(A_out ~ A_in1+ A_in2, tds, hidden=4, threshold=1, stepmax=1e7, rep = 1, startweights = NULL, learningrate.limit= NULL,
learningrate.factor= list(minus = 0.5, plus = 1.2),
learningrate=NULL, lifesign = "full",
lifesign.step= 1000, 
algorithm= c("rprop+"),
err.fct= "sse", act.fct= "logistic",
linear.output= TRUE, exclude= NULL,
constant.weights= NULL, likelihood= FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

I figured a turnaround … it could work … !

Surround the **neuralnet** block with **sink** commands … as follow ….

```
fileName <- file(paste0('neuralnet.log'), "w")

  a <- seq(1:1000)
  b <- a*2
  tds <- cbind(a, b)
  colnames(tds) <- c('a', 'b')

  sink(summary(fileName)$description, append = TRUE) # Direct all output to file
  net.sqrt <- neuralnet(b ~ a, tds, hidden=1, threshold=1, stepmax=1e5, rep = 3, startweights = NULL,
                        learningrate.limit = NULL,
                        learningrate.factor = list(minus = 0.5, plus = 1.2),
                        learningrate=NULL, lifesign = "full",
                        lifesign.step = 1000, 
                        algorithm = c("rprop+"),
                        err.fct = "sse", act.fct = "logistic",
                        linear.output = TRUE, exclude = NULL,
                        constant.weights = NULL, likelihood = FALSE)
  sink() # Turn off buffing to file
  close(fileName)
```

if you have better solution ... appreciate your feedback ...